# Unable to get the records from php script to android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am using android volley library to get the records from database on server. I send a query from my android app to this php script. When I write query myself in 4th line as follows $myquery = "Select firstname from Student;"; then all results are returned correctly but when I send a query directly, it doesn't returns records. I am sure that the issue is in php script, please help me where I am going wrong in this basic script?

```
function showStudent()
{
    global $connect;
    $myquery = $_POST["query"];

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$myquery);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array = array();

    if($number_of_rows>0)
    {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("dataArray"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to receive a query trough an user input??

Comment: actually  i have made a generic class for my use,  i just change queries in different classes  so that is why I  send different queries to the same script

Comment: you might want to log the content of $myquery to check if it is correct. Do something like file_put_contents('/tmp/log', $myquery);

Comment: I see... But that will also leave your server open to query attacks. Just imagine someone sending something like _"DROP TABLE students"_ or _"INSERT INTO users (login, password, is_admin) VALUES ('h4ck3r', '...', 1)"_ . Remember script calls are'nt hard to track and an user could easily input values trough a browser console

Comment: @CarlosCarucce actually what i want to do through this script is fetch records based on query, so if I write query hard codedly  then I would write many scripts like e.g one script for selecting all records, one script for fetching records based on 'where' condition, etc. So that is why I am interested to send query through my android app and receive it in php app so this way only this one script would do the work for fetching records from database

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
$myquery = $_REQUEST['query'];
```

Instead of this

```
$myquery = $_POST["query"];
```